# getline: template argument deduction/substitution failed

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error when I try to read the output of a command line by line:

```
std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
  FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
  if (!pipe) return "";

  char buffer[128];
  std::string result = "";

  while (!feof(pipe)) {
    if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL) {
      result += buffer;
    }
  }

  pclose(pipe);

  return result;
}

string commandStr = "echo Hello World";
const char *command = commandStr.c_str();

std::string output = exec(command);

std::string line; 
while (std::getline(output, line)) {
  send(sockfd, line.c_str(), line.length(), 0); 
}
```

> note: template argument deduction/substitution failed: note:
>   ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ is not derived from
>   ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>’
>   exec(command), line <- Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::getline(output, line)
```

You're trying to call getline with two strings, that's wrong, it takes an istream and a string.

To use getline you need to put the output into a stream:

```
std::istringstream outstr(output);
getline(outstr, line);
```

Comment: Thanks, it says "outstr has initializer but incomplete type" so that means there it needs = NULL?

Comment: No it means you need to `#include <sstream>` which is the header that defines `std::istringstream`

Answer (score 2):

To solve the cause of the error message, I would guess it is from [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). `getline` requires an [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) as its first argument. If you want to read from `output`, you can use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
std::stringstream ss(output);
while (std::getline(ss, line)) {
    /* ... */
}
```